# Issues with Vim Regex

Tags: vim, regex

I have a list of variables I want to compare in the form

```
 acceptEncoding == copy.
 authorization == copy.
 cacheControl == copy.
 contentEncodin == copy.
 contentLength == copy.
...
```

and I want to turn it into

```
acceptEncoding == copy.acceptEncoding &&
authorization == copy.authorization &&
cacheControl == copy.cacheControl &&
contentEncodin == copy.contentEncoding &&
contentLength == copy.contentLength &&
...
```

using :%s in vim. I used the command as `%s/(.+) == copy\./\1 == copy.\1 &&/` but it's not matching any of the instances, yet the regex seems to be correct and works in regex buddy / other regex applications, is there something special about vim :s regex that makes this not work? I've already just went ahead and did it with a macro but I want to know why the regex was failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `( + ) &`

```
%s/\(.\+\) == copy\./\1 == copy.\1 \&\&/
```

This should yield :

```
acceptEncoding == copy.acceptEncoding &&
authorization == copy.authorization &&
cacheControl == copy.cacheControl &&
contentEncodin == copy.contentEncodin &&
contentLength == copy.contentLength &&
...
```